# How can I catch event ExitFullScreen of a video?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, android-browser

How can I catch event ExitFullScreen of a video ?
I need to redraw the page when I exit the FullScreen of tag video.

Answer (score 7):

Listen to the `fullscreenchange` event:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    console.log(document.fullscreen);
}, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
    console.log(document.mozFullScreen);
}, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    console.log(document.webkitIsFullScreen);
}, false);
```

Comment: @SantiagoRebella Android 2.3 [doesn't implement the full screen API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).  In fact neither does any other version of the stock browser.  If you're using Chrome or Firefox on Android then it should work.